# WSS 3.0 Configuration Wizard exception

Tags: wss-3.0, deployment, error, configuration-wizard

After installing WSS 3.0 I'm getting the following error in the configuration wizard:

> An Exception of type
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was
>   thrown. Additional exception
>   information Timeout Expired.The
>   timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding.

Does any one know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems the web server is not able to communicate with the SQL Server. Is there network connectivity between these machines? Can you ping SQL from the web server?

Your problem is most likely that you need to solve a network connectivity issue. Or that SQL really has gone down unexpectedly of course.